# Finding right version of python/sklearn in to use machine learning model in pyenv

Tags: scikit-learn, pickle, pyenv, python-poetry

I pickled a model on Kaggle and tried to download it to run locally. Using poetry and pyenv I ran the following commands to create a project:

```
pyenv local 3.6.6    
poetry new model_api
cd model_test
poetry env use python
poetry add "sklearn>=0.21.3"
```

but received the error below.

[image]

If I simply use sklearn and install it with poetry I get this error when executing my code in VS Code.

```
/bin/python /home/gary/Documents/model_api/model_api/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gary/Documents/model_api/model_api/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    model = pickle.load(f)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.forest'
```

This is the code I am attempting to run.

```
import sklearn 
import pickle

f = open('./model/ForestModel','rb')
model = pickle.load(f)
```

I'm trying to use Python 3.6.6 and sklearn 0.21.3 based on what I'm seeing on Kaggle:
[image]

If I try to use a more current version of Python like 3.8.10 I get the same error. I think I'm missing something simple/obvious. Any pointers or things I could check would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no package `sklearn` with the version you like to be installed. I think you are looking for `scikit-learn` instead ([Docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#installation-instructions)).

You can install the most up to date version that is supported by your other dependencies by running:

```
poetry add scikit-learn
```

Or if you need to install a specific version:

```
poetry add "scikit-learn==0.24.2"
```

For other options, check out the poetry docs [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the Anaconda package manager instead of `pyenv`. You could create an environment with the following code:

- `conda create -n envName sklearn`

And they would probably keep up with the best coordination of Python packages so that you don’t get errors.

Comment: I think this is a bit confusing here. `poetry` does the same. `pyenv` is only used to specify the Python version here and not manage the packages. Poetry will create a virtual environment and resolve dependencies - allow safe updates etc - as needed.